# SqlAlchemy alembic migration files dont use the connection settings in env.py?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a migration that works on a generic schema named `tenant_schema`.
In the `run_migrations_online` function in `env.py` i set up a schema_translate_map for `tenant_schema`.

I expected `sqlalchemy` to translate this migration operation to run on the desired schema, however it seems like it tries to run sql queries using the schema `tenant_schema`.

any ideas how to fix it ?

**example**:

the upgrade function in the migration file:

`2018-09-05_17-28_247f3546088f_add_foo_column.py`

```
def upgrade():
    op.add_column('derived_table', sa.Column('foo', sa.BigInteger(), nullable=True), 
                  schema='tenant_schema')
```

the `run_migrations_online` function:

`env.py`

```
schema = 'other_name'  # normally i get the name as an argument from alembic
def run_migrations_online():
    connectable = create_engine(get_url(), echo=True)

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        # setting up the translation map
        conn = connection.execution_options(schema_translate_map={'tenant_schema': schema})
        context.configure(
            connection=conn,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            include_schemas=True,
            version_table_schema=schema,
            include_object=include_object,
        )
        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

the exception (full traceback is too long and not that informative):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) schema "tenant_schema" does not exist
 [SQL: 'ALTER TABLE tenant_schema.derived_table ADD COLUMN foo BIGINT'] 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

as you can see it tries to do `ALTER TABLE tenant_schema.derived_table` instead of the desired `ALTER TABLE other_name.derived_table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

From the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#translation-of-schema-names) regarding `schema_translate_map` (emphasis mine):

> The feature takes effect only in those cases where the name of the schema is derived directly from that of a Table or Sequence; **it does not impact methods where a string schema name is passed directly**

As all the schemas are passed directly in alembic migration operations, the `schema_translate_map` is not taken into account.

## Solution

What you probably need is:

1. Use alembic hooks to tweak the way schema is added to your migration, so that it is not a literal string but a lookup in some global context (e.g. render `os.environ['TENANT_SCHEMA']` instead of literal string `'tenant_schema'`).

   Probably the right place to hook would be to override the rendering functions, see example in the [docs](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/autogenerate.html#creating-a-render-function).  Unfortunately I cannot show any code for this because I haven't tried this myself.

   Alternatively, you can try to register your custom comparators which would run after alembic's and won't actually compare anything but will replace the `schema` attribute in alembic-generated operations with a custom string subclass:

   ```
   from alembic.autogenerate import comparators

   class FakeSchema(str):
       def __repr__(self):
           return "os.environ['TENANT_SCHEMA']"

   @comparators.dispatch_for('schema')
   def tweak_schema(autogen_context, upgrade_ops, schemas):
       for op in upgrade_ops.ops:
           if getattr(op, 'schema', None) == 'tenant_schema':
               op.schema = FakeSchema(op.schema)
               autogen_context.imports.add('import os')  # for os.environ
   ```

   You can read about comparator functions [in alembic docs](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/autogenerate.html#registering-a-comparison-function).
2. Set the schema name in that global context to the value you need when migrations are run (in this example, pass `TENANT_SCHEMA` environment variable to alembic or add it into `os.environ` in your `env.py`).

Comment: the custom comparators did not work for me, do i have to pass it to `context.configure` (like for example with `process_revision_directives`) ?

Comment: or do i have to write my own custom autogenerate script ?

Comment: No, you just add this to `env.py`, but you'll need to regenerate or manually modify existing migrations to work the same way.

Comment: but how should i add it to the context ?

Comment: I ended up using a rewriter function, but used your `FakeSchema`. thank you very much. enjoy the 50 :)